# How to locate image from a Bytes Android

Tags: java, android, bytestream

Currently i have byte array. Which contains a **.jpg** file also some other unwanted data.

What I wanted to do is to find out the position of data "FF D8" (start of JPEG data).

Same Code in iOS is : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18477915/5215474

Comment: downvoter? plz explain

Comment: Why do you think?  Implementing this is *trivial*.  So trivial that a Java programmer should not need to ask.  Also ... asking someone to translate some code for you is NOT how StackOverflow is intended to be used.

Comment: In objective C, I mean iOS it was not trivial right

Comment: Nope.  But in Java it is.

Comment: But need to know how we can check this substring

Comment: But nothing.  It is simple Java 101 stuff.  Anyone who calls themselves a Java programmer should be able to implement it in 2 minutes.  Anyhow, you asked why the downvotes ... and I expect that is why.

Comment: im iOS programmer.. just helping hands to juniors

Comment: Fine.  So don't use StackOverflow as a free programming resource.  If you are an iOS programmer and you need some Java programming done, either learn Java yourself, or employ a Java programmer.  And if you are learning ... the way to learn is to do it yourself, not ask someone to do it for you.

Comment: thanks for your time/.. maan.. actually i want get the image thats ol... fed up with wifi connection and getting from device and all...

Comment: Sorry.  Bored now.  Off to help someone else.  You've had your 15 minutes of my time.

Comment: hahah tahts good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is trivial to implement in Java.

```
int position = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length - 2; i++) {
    if (bytes[i] == (byte) 0xff && bytes[i + 1] == (byte) 0xdf) {
        position = i;
        break;
    }
}
```